# Escaping both types of quotes in subprocess.Popen call to awk

Tags: python, subprocess

My subprocess call should be calling `tabix 1kg.phase1.snp.bed.gz -B test.bed | awk '{FS="\t";OFS="\t"} $4 >= 10'` but is giving me errors because it has both `"` and `'` in it. I have tried using `r` for a raw string but I can't figure out the right combination to prevent errors. My current call looks like:

```
snp_tabix = subprocess.Popen(["tabix", tgp_snp, "-B", infile, "|", "awk", """'{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}""", "$4", ">=", maf_cut_off, r"'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Which gives the error `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`

Comment: Looks like one of those variables isn't a string. As a guess, maybe `infile` is a file object.

Comment: If I understand your command line right, the single quotes are only needed for shell escaping purposes. But since you're using Popen, which should have ``shell=False``, you don't need them at all because you're not using the shell to determine which bits of the input go to your external programs in which order.

Comment: @MaxNoel: it won't work without a shell due to the pipe (`|`). You need to [reproduce its functionality somehow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20414059/4279).

Answer (score 3):

`r"'"` is not the issue. Most likely you're passing `maf_cut_off` as an integer, which is incorrect. You should use `str(maf_cut_off)`.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I was confused because when I was testing the list with ' '.join() I was getting added backslashes when using the r'' which I guess don't seem to matter.

Comment: converting to strings all the variables along [won't help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20414059/4279)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues. You are trying to execute a shell command (there is a pipe `|` in the command). So it won't work even if you convert all variables to strings.

You could execute it using shell:

```
from pipes import quote
from subprocess import check_output

cmd = r"""tabix %s -B %s | awk '{FS="\t";OFS="\t"} $4 >= %d'""" % (
    quote(tgp_snp), quote(infile), maf_cut_off)
output = check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

Or you could use the [pipe recipe from `subprocess`' docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

tabix = Popen(["tabix", tgp_snp, "-B", infile], stdout=PIPE)
awk = Popen(["awk", r'{FS="\t";OFS="\t"} $4 >= %d' % maf_cut_off],
            stdin=tabix.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
tabix.stdout.close() # allow tabix to receive a SIGPIPE if awk exits
output = awk.communicate()[0]
tabix.wait()
```

Or you could use [`plumbum` that provides some syntax sugar for shell commands](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
from plumbum.cmd import tabix, awk

cmd = tabix[tgp_snp, '-B', infile]
cmd |= awk[r'{FS="\t";OFS="\t"} $4 >= %d' % maf_cut_off]
output = cmd() # run it and get output
```

Another option is to reproduce the `awk` command in pure Python. To get all lines that have 4th field larger than or equal to `maf_cut_off` numerically (as an integer):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

tabix = Popen(["tabix", tgp_snp, "-B", infile], stdout=PIPE)
lines = []
for line in tabix.stdout:
    columns = line.split(b'\t', 4)
    if len(columns) > 3 and int(columns[3]) >= maf_cut_off:
       lines.append(line)
output = b''.join(lines)
tabix.communicate() # close streams, wait for the subprocess to exit
```

`tgp_snp`, `infile` should be strings and `maf_cut_off` should be an integer.

You could use `bufsize=-1` (`Popen()`'s parameter) to improve time performance.