# Subprocess call providing incorrect parameters compared to ' '.join()

Tags: python, subprocess

When I run the command

```
subprocess.call(['intersectBed','-u','-a',out_snv_filter,'-b',cds,'>',out_cds],shell=True)
```

I get the help menu for `intersectBed` reported back in the interpreter.

But when I run

```
>>> ' '.join(['intersectBed','-u','-a',out_snv_filter,'-b',cds,'>',out_cds])
'intersectBed -u -a test/test.out.snv.filter -b gencode7.cds.bed > test/test.out.cds'

$ intersectBed -u -a test/test.out.snv.filter -b gencode7.cds.bed > test/test.out.cds
```

The program runs normally. What is the difference here?

Comment: If I drop shell=True then the `>` stdout piping will not work.

Comment: it is incorrect to use a list argument and `shell=True` (the meaning is different: the first item is a shell command, the rest are args for the shell. I don't think it is what you  want)

Comment: You can check the exact command sent to `subprocess.call` by using `subprocess.list2cmdline` with the list of arguments as a parameter.

Comment: to see an example when `shell=True` might be useful, see [Escaping both types of quotes in subprocess.Popen call to awk](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20412594/4279)

Comment: @Brian: `list2cmdline` is for Windows where `CreateProcess` accepts a string argument. On other systems, a list argument is a better alternative unless you need to run a shell.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Thanks for the clarification.  I have always provided a list of arguments on Windows.  However, I have found the `list2cmdline` function useful for troubleshooting when commands are not working as expected.

Comment: @Brian: for troubleshooting I would just copy-paste a string from a console where I've tested it that it works. Look at `help(subprocess.list2cmdline)` it uses the same rules as the MS C runtime; it may break for anything else (in particular for `/bin/sh` commands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from subprocess import check_call

args = ['intersectBed','-u','-a',out_snv_filter,'-b',cds]
with open(out_cds, 'wb') as outfile:
    check_call(args, stdout=outfile)
```